# Euclidean Distance in 4th Dimension

Tags: matrices, euclidean-geometry

I have found this question in one of my Universities old pass papers and I'm trying to solve this:

You have a fishing rod of length 2 and need to ship it in a box which sides
are not longer than 1. In spaces Rn of at least which dimensional n will
you be able to fit the rod into the box without bending or breaking at the
inter-dimensional post office (which works with Euclidean distances)?
Find the smallest possible dimension n as any additional dimensions cost
extra.

By any chance could someone provide a hint/step on how i can solve this?

Comment: Hint:  $2^2=4$ .

Comment: Hint: imagine the shipping box is $[0,1]^n$ (the unit cube). The longest rod that can fit in the box is the one with endpoints at $(0,\dots,0)$ and $(1,\dots, 1)$. How long is this rod in $n$ dimensions? How big does $n$ have to be so that this rod is at least $2$ in length?

Answer (score 1):

You should write out the formula of the theorem of Pythagoras in $n$ dimensions and ask yourself for which values of $n$ the hypothenuse becomes long enough.